# How to POST data with Spring-boot RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger

Actually, i have this Rest Template request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadProperties", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody RessourceMetadata uploadProperties(
        @RequestParam(value = "group", required = true) String group,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id,
        @RequestParam(value = "version", required = true) String version,
        @RequestParam(value = "env", required = true) String env) {
    try {
        Ressource ressource = new Ressource(content, group, id, version, env, PropertiesFileUtils.getPropertiesFilename());
        getRessourceService().save(ressource);
        return ressource.getMetadata();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        log.error("Error while uploading.", e);
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while uploading.", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I want to add a `@RequestBody` like this:

```
    @RequestBody @RequestParam(value = "content", required = true) ????? content
```

this new `content` can contain anything.

How do I pass the `content` parameter correctly?

Comment: what do you meant by 'can contain anything'? you want to encapsulate all the fields like group, version, id and env into content, is that correct?

Comment: @pvpkiran no, is a new field where I can put code or key / value lines, for example ...
I do not know if it is possible to do what I ask?

Comment: Something is either `@RequestBody` or a `@RequestParam` not both...

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class like this

```
class PostBody{
   Map<String, String> content;
}
```

use this PostBody as `@RequestBody`. You can pass any string key value pair to this structure. Something like this

```
{
"content":
    {
      "version" : "1.1",
      "env" : "test"
    }  
}
```

or

```
{
"content":
    {
      "version" : "1.1",
      "env" : "test",
      "id" : "1.1"
    }  
}
```

Comment: I have this error

    Response Body
    
    {
      "timestamp": 1496133459278,
      "status": 500,
      "error": "Internal Server Error",
      "exception": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
      "message": "'Content-Type' cannot contain wildcard type '*'",
      "path": "/api/test/uploadProperties"
    }

Comment: the error is pretty clear i guess `Content-Type' cannot contain wildcard type '*'` you are passing * in content-type. How are you calling this rest endpoint?

Comment: `curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: */*" --header "Accept: */*" -d "{
\"content\":
    {
      \"version\" : \"1.1\",
      \"env\" : \"test\",
      \"id\" : \"1.1\"
    }  
}" "http://localhost:8080/api/test/uploadProperties?group=a&id=a&version=a&env=a"`

Comment: couple of things. As @Deinum said, you are mixing requestparms wit requestbody, When you have requestbody why are you passing request params as well (in the url after '?'). In your curl what exactly is your content type ?